# Unable to define custom columns and rows while writing mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT SUM(device='Android' OR device='iPhone') AS `Mobile`,
SUM(device='Windows') AS `Desktop`
FROM `table
```

I am getting correct result from it, that is,

```
Mobile      Desktop
123           250
```

But I want a different result and I couldn't find any such function. I need the output to look like:

```
    Platforms   Number
      Mobile     123
      Desktop    250
```

I tried: SELECT 'Mobile' AS Platforms (It achieves the first part, although I couldn't add Desktop to it, not sure how to achieve it)

Comment: can you plz show me your table as well

Comment: You need to add `GROUP BY some_col`

Answer (score 3):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,device VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (device) VALUES
('Android'),
('Windows'),
('iPhone'),
('Bada'),
('Windows'),
('iPhone');

SELECT type
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT CASE WHEN device IN('Android','iPhone') THEN 'Mobile'  
                   WHEN device = 'Windows' THEN 'Desktop' 
                   ELSE device END type 
         FROM my_table
     ) x 
 GROUP 
    BY type;
+---------+-------+
| type    | total |
+---------+-------+
| Bada    |     1 |
| Desktop |     2 |
| Mobile  |     3 |
+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally i don't answer on questions which does not have example data.

```
SELECT 
 'Mobile' AS platsforms
 , SUM(device='Android' OR device='iPhone') AS `Number`
FROM 
 Table

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
 'Desktop' AS platsforms
 , SUM(device='Windows') AS `Number`
FROM 
 Table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` to get `Platforms` column then `group by` with it.

```
SELECT 
       CASE
              WHEN device='Android' OR device='iPhone' THEN 'Mobile' 
              WHEN device='Windows' THEN 'Desktop' 
       END Platforms , 
       Count(*) Number
FROM   `table
where device IN ('Android','iPhone','Windows')
GROUP BY 
      CASE 
              WHEN device='Android' OR  device='iPhone' THEN 'Mobile' 
              WHEN device='Windows' THEN 'Desktop' 
       END
```